# Do I need to tune sysctl.conf under linux when running MongoDB?

Tags: linux, mongodb

We are seeing occational huge writes to disk in the MongoDB log, effectively locking MongoDB for a long time. Many people are reporting similar issues on the net, but I have found no good answers so far.

```
 Tue Mar 11 09:42:49.818 [DataFileSync] flushing mmaps took 75264ms  for 46 files
```

The average mmap flush on my server is around 100 ms according to the mongo statistics.

A large percentage of our MongDB data is updated within a few hours. This leads me to speculate whether we need to tune the Linux sysctl virtual memory parameters as described in the performance guide for Neo4J, another memory mapped tool: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/linux-performance-guide.html

> There are a lot of blocks going out to IO, way more than expected for the write speed we 
>   are seeing in the benchmark. Another observation that can be made is that the Linux kernel
>   has spawned a process called "flush-x:x" (run top) that seems to be consuming a lot of
>   resources.
>
> The problem here is that the Linux kernel is trying to be smart and write out dirty pages
>   from the virtual memory. As the benchmark will memory map a 1GB file and do random writes
>   it is likely that this will result in 1/4 of the memory pages available on the system to 
>   be marked as dirty. The Neo4j kernel is not sending any system calls to the Linux kernel to
>   write out these pages to disk however the Linux kernel decided to start doing so and it 
>   is a very bad decision. The result is that instead of doing sequential like writes down 
>   to disk (the logical log file) we are now doing random writes writing regions of the 
>   memory mapped file to disk.

TOP shows that we indeed have a flush process that has been running a very long time, so this seems to match.

```
      PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
    28352 mongod    20   0  153g 3.2g 3.1g S  3.3 42.3 299:18.36 mongod
     3678 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0  26:27.88 flush-253:1
```

The recommended Neo4J sysctl settings are

```
    vm.dirty_background_ratio = 50
    vm.dirty_ratio = 80
```

Does these settings have any relevance for a MongoDB installation at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "yes".  What values to choose depends very much on your write patterns.  [This](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/33700094220/how-mongodbs-journaling-works) gives background on exactly how MongoDB manages its mappings - it's not anything unexpected.

One wrinkle is that in a web-facing database application, you may care about latency more than throughput.  vm.dirty_background_ratio gives the threshold for starting to write dirty pages, and vm.dirty_ratio tells when to stop accepting new writes (ie, block) until all writes have been flushed.

If you are hammering a relatively small working set, you can be OK with setting both of those values fairly high, and relying on Mongo's (or the OS's) periodic time-based flush-to-disk to commit the writes.

If you're conducting a high volume of inserts and also some modifications, which sounds like it might be your situation, it's a balancing act that depends on inserts vs. rewrites - starting to flush too early will cause writes that will be re-written soon, "wasting" io.  Starting to flush too late will result in pauses as you flush huge writes.

If you're doing mostly inserts, then you may very well want a large dirty_ratio (to avoid blocking) and a relatively small dirty_background_ratio (small enough to always be writing as you're inserting to reduce latency, and just large enough to linearize some of the writes).

The correct solution is to replay some dummy data with various options for those sysctl parameters, and optimize it by brute force, bearing in mind your average latency / total throughput objectives.

Comment: This is really helpful as we are quite sensitive to latency.